# m2e autocomplete for cuatom properties not working

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I have this configuration:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.webinf.dir>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF</project.webinf.path>
</properties>
```

My autocomplete feature from custom properties in Maven 2 Eclipse (m2e) is not working for pom.xml files in the editor. The only thing that is working is the properties such as `${basedir}`, `${project.artifactId}`, etc.

The properties work, the problem is the autocomplete only.
**EDIT: The properties do not work, I equivocated myself.**

Is there any bug related to this or this could be a misconfiguration of my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement:

> The properties work, the problem is the autocomplete only.

was equivocated, I assumed it was working but it wasn't.

The thing is I was setting the properties to the `project.*` namespace, when I changed to `<webinf.dir>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF</webinf.path>` it worked like a charm (the properties and the autocomplete).

Probably there is some kind of restriction for adding a new property to an existed workspace.
If you have some answer that explains how this works in details I would be very happy to accept.